# Выделение ссылки на якорь и сохранение ее стиля только средствами html css

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на ссылку сделать, например, ее бг красным, но после нажатия на другую ссылку, применить такой стиль на нее, а у прошлой убрать. Возможно ли сделать такое без JS?

Примерный код:

```
<a href="#id1">1</a>
<a href="#id2">2</a>
<a href="#id3">2</a>

<div class="txt" id="id1">
    <p>1</p>
</div>

<div class="txt" id="id2">
    <p>2</p>
</div>

<div class="txt" id="id3">
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: пробовал через :focus , но при переходе он сбрасывается

Comment: Без javascript - нет